# Returning Lists in SharePoint 2013 CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I'm working with SharePoint 2013 and trying to return all the lists that exist within a Site URL.  I've tried the code below, but it returns an initialization error.  How can I properly return these lists?

```
foreach (List li in clientContext.Web.Lists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(li.Title);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own.  A new `ListCollection` needs to be created, then the `ListCollection` pulled down from the SharePoint server can be populated into it after `ExecuteQuery` is called.  See example below.

```
ListCollection lc = clientContext.Web.Lists;
clientContext.Load(lc);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (List l in lc)
    {
        {
            //Do work here
        }
    }
```